# 405 - Method Not Allowed in Robot Framework

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, pycharm, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework. I was trying to access an URL and generate a token.

I am getting the below error.

```
Test 1                                                                | FAIL |
405 != 200
```

upon checking the log

```
00:52:49.347    INFO    POST Response : 
url=XXX 
status=405, reason=Method Not Allowed 
body=None
```

URL is getting passed correctly and the same is working fine in Postman.

```
 Create Session  myssion  ${auth_url}
 ${response}=   Post Request  myssion  /oauth2/token     auth=${auth} headers=${headers}  
 grant_type=${grant_type}

 Should Be Equal As Strings  ${response.status_code}  200
 ${token}=    evaluate    $resp.json().get("access_token")
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you add the JSON you use in Postman (after removing secrets)?

Comment: The code in the question has just one space between `${auth}` and `headers=`. Is that how your real code is?

Comment: thanks bryan for the assitance

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the problem is a missing space. You only have one space between `auth=${auth}` and `headers=${headers}`. You need two or more spaces:

```
${response}=   Post Request  myssion  /oauth2/token  auth=${auth}  headers=${headers}
                                                                 ^^
```

Comment: It is working now after adding the space. thank you